# Returning a blank cell (not an empty string) from an IF in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Currently I have an Excel formula which reads:

`=IF(ISBLANK(F24),"",F24*$C24)`

However, if F24 is blank, this formula does not return an empty cell. It returns an empty string, which causes a #VALUE error if there is any arithmetic formula operating on the column.

The arithmetic will work if the formula is changed to:

`=IF(ISBLANK(F24),,F24*$C24)`

But then the cell is shown containing a zero, which makes a mess of the spreadsheet since it contains sparse data.

Can an IF statement specify that a cell should be considered zero-empty on a given condition?

Comment: Have it return `0` then use a custom number format that makes the 0 look like an empty cell. `General;General;;`

Comment: The cell cannot be blank and contain a formula at the same time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel) from stack overflow. Looks like it requires a little VB, but it is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting invalid data in the cells that I wanted my scatter plot to ignore. My particular IF statement is:

IF(AR25>$AS$24,T25,1/0)

If the condition is not met the result in the cell is:  #DIV/0!

My scatter plot (points connected with no markers) did not ignore these cells but treated them as having the value 0.

I ended up hard setting the cells (points) that I did not want plotted to the value of a point that I know will always be part of my plot, i.e. I buried the problem points at a good point in my plot.  This kluge worked.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a way to put truly NULL values into excel, tho it is kinda hokey.

What I am after, is the ability to jump across many empty cells (note:  not containing formulas) onto the next non-blank cell.  The following accomplishes that . . .

## Fill your cells with the desired formula:

=if(C1="it","Yay!","")

Copy / Paste this to all cells you are interested in. 
  Save the file as a .csv file.

Reopen the .csv file into Excel.  All the blank fields are now NULL.

If you need to preserve some previous formatting or whatever, save the regular excel file (w/ formatting), then save the same file as .csv.  When you reopen the .csv file, paste over the values into the formatted .xlsx. file.

And there you have it!

Comment: But this permanently destroys the formula.  If `C1` (in your answer) or `F24` (in the question) is subsequently modified, the cell that had the formula will not change.